# What is the complexity of an algorithm if inputs are constrained by a constant number?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've seen coding problems that are similar to this:

```
int doSomething(String s)
```

Where it says in the problem description that `s` will contain at most one of every character, so `s` cannot be more than length 26. I think in this case, iterating over `s` would be constant time.

But I've also seen problems where inputs are constrained to a random large number, like 10^5, just to avoid stack overflows and other weird edge cases. If we are going to consider inputs that are constrained by constants to be constant complexity, shouldn't these inputs also be considered constant complexity?

But it doesn't make sense to me to consider `s` to be of O(n) complexity either, because there are many problems were people allocate char[26] arrays to hold every letter of the alphabet. How does if make sense to consider an input that we know will be less than or equal to 26 to be of greater complexity than an array of size 26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of analyzing the complexity of algorithms is to estimate how long it will take to run it. If the problem you're trying to solve limits the maximum value of `n` to a constant, you can consider `n` to be a constant and you wouldn't be wrong. But would that be useful if you wanted to predict whether an algorithm that does `2^n` operations will run in a few seconds for `n = 26`? On the other hand, if you had an algorithm that does `n*m` operations and `m` is at most 3, how useful would it be to include `m` in the complexity analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating complexity has focus on what is the most critical variable related to the running time. If the running time is dominant by the length of `s`, it is our main focus of analyzing complexity and that should be in bigO notation. And in that case, of course it's not a constant.

If the input is constrained to a large number like 10^5.

And if the algorithm is getting slower proportional to that input.

for example,

```
int sort(string s); //length of s is less than 10^5
```

In this case, depending on what sorting algorithm you use,
the running time will be proportional to the length of `s`

like `O(n^2) or O(nlogn)` if `n` is the length of s

In this case you cannot say it's constant because running time is very different as the length of s is changing.

But if the algorithm inside has nothing to do with the length of `s`, like it has constant calculation time, then you can say 10^5 constraint is just a constant.